# Find Nearby Places from the current location in windows phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8, geolocation

The new map controls in Windows Phone 8 is very good with new features. My windows phone app wants to extend this functionality by providing the users a nearby places recommendation after they have reached their destination. 
Any suggestive links or code snippets available for the same?.

Thanks In Advance.

Comment: Please refer to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4708704/web-service-to-find-nearby-points-of-interest

Answer (score 0):

To make this clear what you are looking is an open API for nearby POIs based on user's location.

In addition to my comment also check: http://openpoi.ogcnetwork.net/